# Boto3 - Can I get items with batch_get_item whose sort key begins with a variable?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm using boto3 to deal with AWS Dynamo DB.

I'd like to **query once** to get items whose sort key **begins with** some variable in **two partition keys**.

I've read documents many times, but the examples are all about getting items that **exactly match** partition key and sort key.

I know it's possible for **one partition** key to get items whose sort key begins with `ABC_`.

```py
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('partition_key').eq(partition_key1) & 
                           Key('sort_key').begins_with('ABC_')
)
response2 = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('partition_key').eq(partition_key2) & 
                           Key('sort_key').begins_with('ABC_')
)
```

But is it also possible to **query once** to get multiple items in two partition keys whose sort key begins with `ABC_`?

```py
response = dynamodb.batch_get_item(
    RequestItems={
        'test_table': {
            'Keys': [
                {
                    'partition_key': partition_key1,
                    'sort_key': 'ABC_1',  # begins with 'ABC_'
                },
                {
                    'partition_key': partition_key2,
                    'sort_key': 'ABC_2',  # begins with 'ABC_'
                },
            ],
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: No, you need to perform 2 queries.

Answer (score 2):

No, you will need to use two queries. Execute them in parallel if you need a faster response.